# How to get items in listbox in to Settings.Default C#

Tags: c#

Im trying to save the items in the listbox in Settings.Default but it will not work, this is what i have so far.

```
test.Properties.Settings.Default.list = listBox1.Items;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with an `ArrayList`?

```
test.Properties.Settings.Default.list = new ArrayList(listBox1.Items);
test.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Then you could load the list back like so:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(test.Properties.Settings.Default.list.ToArray());
```

I'm also assuming that the items in your list are serializable (either implement `ISerializable` or have the `SerializableAttribute`).

Answer (score 1):

Changes to properties will not persist if you don't call `Save()` afterwards.

```
test.Properties.Settings.Default.list = listBox1.Items;
test.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```