# where is System.Collections.arraylist in Settings

Tags: c#

I guess it's a silly question, but maybe someone could help me...

I'm trying to find System.Collections.arraylist in the Settings tab of the project and can't seem to find it. Am I missing something here?

I want  to save a listbox (in the form of Arraylist) to the Settings so I need to save a parameter of type: System.Collections.arraylist.

```
 Properties.Settings.Default.listbox_items = new ArrayList(PkgFilesListbox.Items);
```

So, basically, `listbox_items` should be of type System.Collections.Array, right?

But I can't find it in VS2012 in the Settings tab (in the project properties). I have bool, int, string, System, etc., but under System, there's no Collections.

just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241763/how-to-get-items-in-listbox-in-to-settings-default-c-sharp)

Comment: you need to show actual code and the example in the link is pretty self explanatory why can't you get it to work.. did you right click on y our project and select add new item, then select Settings File..?

Comment: ArrayList isnt there - use the string collection

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/arraylist

Answer (score 0):

From the type dropdown box choose "Browse...":

[image: Select browse...]

A dialog will open up - you should be able to find System.ArrayList.Collections in there. (If you can't, just type it in the textbox at the bottom of the dialog - that's probably easier anyway)

[image: Enter the type name]